# How to insert data from database using oops php concepts?

Tags: php

I try to insert one person detail, it's inserted successfully. If i check in DB "same data insert 3 times".  Why the data insert 3 times?

I had this data in the Database.

```
id      name       dob             gen
1       James     12-03-1977        M
2       James     12-03-1977        M
3       James     12-03-1977        M
```

PHP class

```
class Detail
{
function savePerson_detail($vars){
    foreach($vars as $key => $value){
       if(is_numeric($key) && $value >0){
         $qry = sprintf("INSERT INTO cca_student_list(per_name, per_dob, per_gen) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s')",
        mysql_real_escape_string($vars['name']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($vars['dob']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($vars['gen']));
        mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
         if($qry)
    {
    print 'Successfully Insert your details';
    }
   }
}
```

Html Page

```
<?php
$detail = new Detail();
if(isset($_POST['btnSaveDetail'])){
   $detail->savePerson_detail($_POST);
}?>
```

Comment: your question title is not quite related to your question content...

Comment: could you make a print_r() of the $_POST variable?

Answer (score 1):

You actually run the query three times, that is why you insert the data three times. Just run the query one time and you should be fine.

To do this you need to change your code: First sanitize the input data in full, *then* run the query. You are currently picking each element of `$vars` (which has three elements) and then you run the query *each* time.

Do one step after the other:

```
function savePerson_detail($vars)
{
    // validate function input
    foreach($vars as $key => $value)
    {
       if(!is_numeric($key) || !$value >0)
         return;
    }

    // build sql query
    $qry = sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO cca_student_list(per_name, per_dob, per_gen) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s')",
        mysql_real_escape_string($vars['name']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($vars['dob']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($vars['gen'])
    );

    // run sql query
    $result = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());

    // check query result
    if($result)
    {
        print 'Successfully Insert your details';
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a little suggestion: this function could return true or false instead of using `print`. Or maybe throw an Exception that the main php file should catch

Comment: Yeah and it coulb be using PDO, dependency injection, real validation, a builder for the SQL string, parameterization of the data configuration in use etc. There is a lot which comes to mind that is bad with it, but for me was important to first step ahead from the original code to deal with the logical flaw it had.

Answer (score 0):

Because you used

```
foreach($vars as $key => $value){
```

When `$vars` or `$_POST` which was passed to it looks like this.

```
$_POST['name'] = 'James';
$_POST['dob'] = '12-03-1977';
$_POST['gen'] = 'M';
```

So it went through each of your `$_POST` items 3 times.
I think you can remove the validation and do it like this.

```
function savePerson_detail($vars){
  $qry = sprintf("INSERT INTO cca_student_list(per_name, per_dob, per_gen) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s')", mysql_real_escape_string($vars['name']), mysql_real_escape_string($vars['dob']), mysql_real_escape_string($vars['gen']));
  mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
  if($qry)
    { print 'Successfully Insert your details'; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, is this what you're trying to do?

```
class Detail
{
function savePerson_detail($vars) {
     foreach($vars as $key => $value) {
          $vars[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
     }

     if($qry)
     {
       print 'Successfully Insert your details';
     }

   $qry = sprintf("INSERT INTO cca_student_list(per_name, per_dob, per_gen) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s')";
   mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
}
```